# when i type in the command: kubectl get pods, in the status column, I am getting "ImagePullBackOff". How do i resolve it?

Tags: minikube

command: kubectl get pods
error: ImagePullBackOff

I am expecting the status of the pod to be running. I have typed in the correct image name and the internet connection is also proper.
why am i getting the error and how do i resolve it?